# How to define move assignment operator for const ref member of template class

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, move-semantics, const-reference

I have the following template class, where the member is `const ref` type. Copying of object is disabled and wanted to only have move cntor and move assignment operator.

**Q1**: How to implement move assignment operator for `const ref type` properly(Is it correct, what I made)?

**Q2**: Why this

```
MyClass<int> obj2(std::move(obj));   // will work with move ctor
MyClass<int> obj3 = std::move(obj2); // also move ctor called: Why?
```

happened?

**Q3**: In `main()` moved instances are able to called using `print()`. Is it UB?

I am using *Visual Studio 2015 (v140)*.
Here is my Code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Type>
class MyClass
{
    const Type& m_ref;  // const ref type
public:
    explicit MyClass(const Type& arg): m_ref(std::move(arg)){}

    // coping is not allowed
    MyClass(const MyClass&) = delete;
    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&) = delete;

    // enables move semantics
    MyClass(MyClass &&other) : m_ref(std::move(other.m_ref)) { std::cout << "Move Cotr...\n"; } // works

    // how would I do the move assignment operator, properly: following?
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass &&other)
    {
        // this should have been done in initilizer list(due to const ref member), 
        // but here we cannnot and still it gives no errors, why?

        this->m_ref = std::move(other.m_ref);  
        std::cout << "Move =operator...\n";
        return *this;
    }

    // print the member
    const void print()const noexcept { std::cout << m_ref << std::endl; }
};

//test program
int main() {
    MyClass<int> obj(2);
    MyClass<int> obj2(std::move(obj));   // will work with move ctor
    MyClass<int> obj3 = std::move(obj2); // also move ctor called: Why?

    obj.print();  // why this prints 2? : is it UB?
    obj2.print(); // why this prints 2? : is it UB?
    obj3.print(); // here it makes sence.

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first:

```
MyClass<int> obj2(std::move(obj));   // will work with move ctor
```

is [*direct initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).

The second:

```
MyClass<int> obj3 = std::move(obj2); // also move ctor called: Why?
```

is [*copy initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

Both are constructing objects (`obj2` and `obj3` respectively) and initialize them. The `=` doesn't mean assignment in this context.

Comment: That was helpful

Answer (score 4):

- Q1

You can't have *any* assignment of a `const &` member. You can invoke *the referenced object's* assignment operators.

- Q2

Both of those are definitions. Neither is an assignment. C++ has redundant syntaxes.

- Q3

It's not undefined behaviour. A moved-from object is still an object. "Moving" an `int` is identical to copying an `int`, because there's no point in changing the source. A `MyClass<std::string>` would print an empty string when moved-from

As a point of note, an `operator=` does not have a member initialiser, because the object already exists.

You seem to be trying to make a move-only `std::reference_wrapper`. I don't think this is a good idea, as your "moves" are actually just copies. C++ does not allow you to create a `unique_reference` type. The closest I can think of getting is a `std::unique_ptr<std::reference_wrapper<T>>`, but even then, you can't ensure that there are no other references to the underlying object

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, you can't easily shallow-move an object that contains a reference member to some content it owns.

If it does *not* own the contents then of course you can simply make a copy of that reference; but if the donor object in the move will attempt to delete the reference on destruction, you have a problem, which we will discuss further.

It may be possible that the target content of the reference can itself be moved, and then your object move would need to perform a move on the reference, creating a new instance of that referenced item that is 'live' and 'killing' the original.

Another option is to use a pointer instead of a reference. Then you can easily shallow-move the pointer, setting the donor pointer to nullptr. You could create a wrapper for the pointer that exposes stub methods to the reference, if there are not too many, to keep your existing code functional. Any direct use of value members can't be so easily obfuscated.

A very weak option is to have a flag in your object that denotes ownership. On move the flag is cleared, and on destruction the references are not destroyed if the flag is cleared. The weakness is that if the donor is not deleted immediately after the move then it is in an inconsistent state. Members that *have* been shallow-moved are probably no longer compatible to the referenced content which is still accessible.